# How to recursively traverse root directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, traversal, tree-traversal

I'm writing **pure C** application which should be able to traverse some directory recursively. When I set `/` as this directory and application starts at some time I get fails of `lstat()` - I get list of nodes in directory and later when I'm doing `lstat()` on some of these nodes it fails. This often happens in `/proc` filesystem.

I know that this is dynamic filesystem which could be changed very often.

**How can I traverse these filesystems?** When at any time getting snapshot (nodes of directory) can be different from real state of filesystem.
Also `find / -iname "*"` doesn't fails and shows files including inside `/proc`.

Comment: I'm sorry, this sounds like a dumb question, but which language are you using to write the application?

Comment: pure C application, with using libc and glib libraries.

Comment: 'find' only gets the entries of the directory; it does not stat the entries individually. Had  you done a stat on the entries ("find /proc/  |xargs stat >/dev/null"), you would have got a ENOENT for the stale files.

Comment: But how this possible if find is traversing recursively? To get entries of directory 'find' should know that it's directory. How it can get entries of /var/tmp/test directory without checking that /var and later /var/tmp/ are directories too?